# Can we recover audio from MFCC coefficients?

Tags: audio, speech-recognition

Can be get an audio signal back from its MFCC coefficients? Also do MFCC coefficients have a range of value if so what is it and if not how do you normalize it between 0 to 1.

I tried using the following MATLAB code:

http://labrosa.ee.columbia.edu/matlab/rastamat/

but the recovered audio is no where similar to the original signal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question better fits [dsp stackexchange](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/search?q=mfcc).

You can not repair exact signal from MFCC, it drops some information on the way so the signal must be similar but not exactly the same. Usually it's lower quality. You can find examples at http://www.research.ibm.com/haifa/projects/multimedia/recovc/demo/index.html.

You can always normalize any real-valued dataset to 0..1 range. One approach is to normalize std/variation from the experimental data. If your data is `x = {x1, x2, x3,....}` then you can consider `(x_i - mean(x))/std(x)`. Second approach is apply any mapping function like `arctan`. Usually such normalization is not needed.